# ERROR [PackageLoader] No driver (HTTP) has been selected. In order to take advantage of the default driver

Tags: node.js, nestjs, node-modules, nestjs-config

I was following a tutorial on Udemy Execution using npx ts-node-dev src/main.ts I get the error [PackageLoader] No driver (HTTP) has been selected. In order to take advantage of the default driver, please, ensure to install the "@nestjs/platform-express" package ($ npm install @nestjs/platform-express). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling @nestjs/platform-express but I still get same error.

I tried many time to run this command $ npm install @nestjs/plateform-express but I still face this issue.

Comment: Any chance you can link to your project? How did you create the Nest server application? What version of `@nestjs/common` and `@nestjs/core` do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It was caused by hoisiting packages by Yarn. Because of different versions, platform-express went to top when other nestjs packages stayed in the deep level folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted my node_modules and installed packages with `yarn install`
then it resolved.